# Encrypt decrypt password with ToBase64String() - special characters are replaced by?

Tags: c#, encryption

I am using following code to encrypt decrypt text:

```
public static string Encrypt(string inputText)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText))
            return string.Empty;
        else
        {
            ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
            RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = myRijndael.CreateEncryptor(_key, _iV);
            MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            byte[] toEncrypt = textConverter.GetBytes(inputText);
            csEncrypt.Write(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string inputText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText))
                return string.Empty;
            else
            {
                inputText = inputText.Replace(" ", "+");

                byte[] encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
                ASCIIEncoding textConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();
                RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

                ICryptoTransform decryptor = myRijndael.CreateDecryptor(_key, _iV);
                MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encrypted);
                CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                byte[] fromEncrypt = new byte[encrypted.Length];
                csDecrypt.Read(fromEncrypt, 0, fromEncrypt.Length);
                return textConverter.GetString(fromEncrypt).TrimEnd('\x0');
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

If I try to encrypt **äöü++++2014M** after decryption it returns **???++++2014M**.

What can I do to get same text?

Thanks,

Priya

Comment: `Base64` is **NOT** an encryption scheme - after all, you can "decrypt" it again without any issue, without having to know a secret or a passphrase or anything. It's just a different representation of the same values - but it's **NOT** an encryption!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using `ASCIIEncoding`. ASCII does not support these characters (äöü) and replaces them with question marks.

You could use `UTF8Encoding` instead.